# After polymer upgrade paper-checkboxes are created twice when loaded as HTML import

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, paper-elements, html-imports

## Problem

I upgraded polymer from 0.5 to 1.5 and paper-checkboxes now appear twice.

## Progress

I tried running polyup and went through the whole polymer upgrade guide but none of the procedures solved this problem. I did find two things:

### 1.

When working correctly the html looks like

```
paper-checkbox
  checkboxContainer
  checkboxLabel
```

I found in my case it looks like

```
paper-checkbox
  checkboxContainer
  checkboxLabel
    checkboxContainer
    checkboxLabel
```

This leads me to believe that polymer is processing the paper-checkbox twice. However, I double checked and I am not loading paper-checkbox.html more than once which was my only idea on that front.

### 2.

The main content is in a fly-in whose sections are loaded as html imports. I found that a paper-checkbox in the imported html exhibits the behavior, but if I hard code a paper-checkbox into the fly-in it works correctly.

## Question

What would cause polymer to try to process the paper-checkbox twice? What about html imports could be causing this?

## Edit:

Code dump at Tony's request.

default.html

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles//font-awesome.css?ver=v2.3.2-22-g83c2652" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css?ver=v2.3.2-22-g83c2652" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css?ver=v2.3.2-22-g83c2652" shim-shadowdom />
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="img/favicon.ico" />

    <!-- HTML Imports -->
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
    <link rel="import" id="doc_nav" href="page/nav.html" onerror="handleError(event)">
    <link rel="import" id="order_billing" href="page/billing.html" onerror="handleError(event)">
    <link rel="import" id="order_submit" href="page/certify.html" onerror="handleError(event)">
</head>
<body>
  // Some generic html then this, the section the imports are added to
  <article class="fly-in transition-out">
  </article>

  // The relevant script
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // when imports are loaded, render starting page
    window.addEventListener('HTMLImportsLoaded', function () {
      init();
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

import.js relevant function

```
// render all the pages of order type to the DOM then hide them
function renderOrderPages(){
    var pages = document.querySelectorAll("link[id^='order_']");
    var article = document.querySelector("article");

    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; ++i) {
        var pg_content = pages[i].import;
        var pg_section = pg_content.querySelector('section');
        pg_section.style.display = "none";
        article.appendChild(pg_section.cloneNode(true));
        bind_page_events(pg_section.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code in the question?

Comment: @tony19 Sure thing.

Comment: Can you show the code where you use `paper-checkbox`?

Comment: @miyamoto `<paper-checkbox>Title</paper-checkbox>`

Comment: @disso There's not enough context to determine the cause of the problem.  The browser's network stack automatically de-dupes all requests from the same URL, but even if it didn't, HTML imports would not cause duplicated elements.

Comment: @tony19 It turned out to be the clone in `article.appendChild(pg_section.cloneNode(true));`. I don't know how it happens though or why it changed presumably from 0.5 to 1.0. Would love some answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, deep node-cloning (`cloneNode(true`) doesn't properly handle `<paper-checkbox>`'s template in Polymer 1.x (which is contained in `<dom-module>`), whereas it previously had no trouble in Polymer 0.5 (where the container was `<polymer-element>`).

While I can't explain with any certainty why `cloneNode(true)` is duplicating the template of `paper-checkbox` in Polymer 1.x, I can provide an alternative:

Change `<section>` to [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template), and `cloneNode()` to [`importNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode):

```
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; ++i) {
    var pg_content = pages[i].import;
    var template = pg_content.querySelector('template');
    var node = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    article.appendChild(node);
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hfdf41HXlYHnMM5FrUZc?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, does `importNode()` only work with `<template>`? What's going on there?

Comment: Note: `template` tags get removed on import, so it's better to wrap your existing HTML in template tags than to change your existing ones to `template` (otherwise you lose your outer element).